btn://site.ru вместо https://site.ru - Что это и откуда?
Обнаружила в Яндекс Метрике значительное количество "страниц" своего сайта, заходы на которые приходят по протоколу btn вот такого вида:
btn://site.ru/?p=;1AA13AAA1A1A1{1A1A&H=65476995467&C=675387647938
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это и откуда берется? За квартал таких заходов почти 6 тысяч.
Сайт в браузере по данным адресам, понятно, не открывается. Но откуда-то Метрика "собирает" эти заходы. И они негативно влияют на общую скорость загрузки (в статистике они отображаются как страницы сайте с временем загрузки 30 сек)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, откуда берутся такие заходы?
Спасибо
P.S. Сайт по аренде спецтехники. Написан на joomla. Данные получены из отчета "Время загрузки страниц", там не указано с какого устройства был просмотр. В других отчетах я таких url не вижу

что за сайт? это урл с которого приходят или на который приходит? какое устройство - мобильное, десктоп?

Сайт по аренде спецтехники. Данные из отчета "Время загрузки страниц", там не указано с какого устройства был просмотр. В других отчетах я таких url не вижу

добавь скриншот, как это у тебя выглядит

может переходы по рендеригу на клиенте? сайт на чем?

Скриншот добавила.

Сайт на cms joomla
